# Entity Framework is not working in N-Tier Architecture

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am building a desktop based application on visual studio 2012. Entity Framework is not working as `SaveChanges()` occur it does not give an exception, it seems that data has been entered but after refreshing database no extra row is added in it.

For demo I made 2-Tier Architecture.

- View
- Data Access Layer

My View is......

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyDAL dal = new MyDAL();
            if (dal.Add(StudentName.Text, Contact.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Addition Successfull");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Addition Failed");
            }
        }
    }
```

My Data Access Layer........

```
    public class MyDAL
    {
        public bool Add(string name, string contact)
        {
            using (var db = new Database1Entities())
            {
                Student s = new Student();
                s.StudentName = name;
                s.ContactNo = contact;

                try
                {
                    db.Students.Add(s);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And My database Script is.....

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student] (
    [Student_Id]  INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentName] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [ContactNo]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Student_Id] ASC)
);
```

My App.Config in View

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

My App.Config in DAL is....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database1Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as intended.  This is a simple misunderstanding of the `|DataDirectory|` option.

When you compile your solution, the database is being copied to the `\Debug\|DataDirectory|` and there the file is being modified.

Most likely you are looking at the file in the solution (visual studio), which is *not* being modified by the executable in the `Debug` directory.

Comment: So how can I get the modified database as `Debug folder` is present in View as well as in DAL...

Comment: Thanks alot `Erik`...You made my day :)........I changed the |DataDirectory| with the absolute path of the database and it worked perfectly as expected